# Should LambdaClient object be shared?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have a question about AWS lambda functions clients in Java. Right now, I call my functions as follows:

```
fun invokeMyLambda(){
    client=LambdaClient.builder().build()
    client.invoke()
}
```

But I don't think that building a client on every invocation is a good practice. Unfortunately, I can't find any helpful information in [Amazon JavaDoc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaClient.html) either. I can't really tell if I can reuse the client like this:

```
val client=LambdaClient.builder().build()

fun invokeMyLambda(){
    
    client.invoke()
}
```

Is it thread-safe? Should I create a pool of clients? Not really clear to me.

Comment: That doesn't look like java. Is it kotlin?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes. but it doesn't really matter. consider it pseudocode. the important thing is that the library is written in Java.

Comment: Ok. I checked it in production. Don't create AWS lambda clients on every call as it causes OOM issues. Create it once and reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LambdaClient must be internally using an HttpClient. And HttpClients are designed to be thread safe and expected to be shared. However it is really hard to answer this question with certainty without examining what LambdaClient internally using. What I recommend to you is to check what LambdaClient internally using by a decompiler (IntelliJ will work). And most likely you will find a thread safe HttpClient internally being used.

For Example
[https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html#:~:text=HttpClient%20is%20fully%20thread%2Dsafe,connection%20manager%20such%20as%20MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.&text=At%20the%20same%20time%20the,all%20threads%20for%20maximum%20efficiency](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html#:%7E:text=HttpClient%20is%20fully%20thread%2Dsafe,connection%20manager%20such%20as%20MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.&text=At%20the%20same%20time%20the,all%20threads%20for%20maximum%20efficiency).

Reuse the HttpClient instance
Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application. However, if the application makes use of HttpClient only very infrequently, and keeping an idle instance of HttpClient in memory is not warranted, it is highly recommended to explicitly shut down the multithreaded connection manager prior to disposing the HttpClient instance. This will ensure proper closure of all HTTP connections in the connection pool.